# How to create API in WSO2 using Eclipse Java EE

Tags: wso2

I am really new in services and mainly in WSO2 and i am having some little problems to finish the tutorial of the link: 'https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/Sending+a+Simple+Message+to+a+Service'.

I need of this tutorial to learn about the use of the tool and because of my boss asked me for.

My problem is, i was able to create the server, i had to create locally, but stopped in the part: 'Sending requests to WSO2 EI', in the item 3, my API simply don't appears. I already tried to restart the server and review the tutorial, but every-time i brake in this part.

I really need help and really want learn. If anyone could help me, i would stay very grateful. Thank you everyone

PS: Remembering that i haven't use any code to come where i come, just tried for the way that the tutorial taught.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem. The reason I had this problem was because I wasn't packaging the artifacts correctly. Once I learned how to package the artifacts, the API showed just right.